# inserting json object into already existing json object inside of a json array

Tags: arrays, json

lets say I have a json array called arr, which contains some number of json objects, jsobj1, jsboj2,... jsbojn. if I want to add a new json object jsobjm inside of jsobj2 how would I do that?

I tried to do arr.get(1).put("jsobjm", jsobjm), but I get the error cannot find symbol, pointing to the . before the put().

Comment: Please add a language tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do this (instead of manipulating the array as a String):

1. Convert the JSON array into it's object equivalent and add the object you want using the programming language you use.
2. Convert the object back to JSON

eg using Javascript

```
let arr = '[{\"name\":\"Ford\"}]';
//convert to object
let objArray = JSON.parse(arr);
let obj = objArray[0];

//add the other object you want into the first object
obj.description = {"reason":"My fav car"};
console.log(obj);

//convert everything back to string
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/allkenang/tuvxrgj3/8/